# Is it true that $\vec v\cdot \vec v=\vec v^T\cdot \vec v^T$?

Tags: proof-verification, inner-products

> Let $\vec v\in\mathbb R^2$. Prove that the linear map $L\colon\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ given by $L(\vec x)=\vec v^T\vec x$ is continuous.

I have a question about my proof:

Consider $\vec x_0\in\mathbb R^2. $Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $\delta=\frac{1}{\lVert\vec v^T\rVert}$. Then
$$\lVert \vec v^T\vec x-\vec v^T\vec x_0\rVert =\lVert \vec v^T(\vec x-\vec x_0)\rVert\leq\lVert \vec v^T\rVert \lVert \vec x-\vec x_0\rVert<\epsilon.
$$
Am I allowed to use the norm of $\vec v^T$? Is it true that
$$
\vec v\cdot \vec v=\vec v^T\cdot \vec v^T,
$$
where we use the standard dot product?

Comment: What even *is* $v^T\cdot v^T$?  Surely you aren't implying that the dot product on the left of the equation is the *same* dot product on the right...

Comment: $| a^T\cdot b|≤\|a\|\,\|b\|$ is also known as the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.